# Lenovo BIOS WMI - InvalidQuery

Tags: c#, wmi, bios

I'm about to create a tool which gets some system information.
Only the Lenovo BIOS (WakeOnLAN) request isn't doing what I want.

The debugger always stops with a "invalid request" error message.

I tried the following...

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\root\\wmi", "SELECT * FROM Lenovo_BiosSetting WHERE InstanceName='ACPI\\PNP0C14\\1_0'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\root\\wmi:Lenovo_BiosSetting.InstanceName='ACPI\\PNP0C14\\1_0'");
```

Code:

```
//LenovoWOL
        public string GetLenovoWOL()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\root\\wmi:Lenovo_BiosSetting", "SELECT * FROM ACPI\\PNP0C14\\1_0");
            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
            {
                try
                {
                    return Environment.NewLine + wmi.GetPropertyValue("CurrentSetting").ToString();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return "Unknown";
        }
```

Only if I remove the InstanceName part, the code works.

Could someone if you tell me, what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your help

Adrian

Comment: what line of code is the error being thrown..? can you tell us?

Comment: VisualStudio marked the word "in" in green. " foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get()) "

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Here my code. It's not pretty but it works.

```
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath()
{
     NamespacePath = @"root\wmi",
     Server = textBox1.Text
};
     ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path);
     SelectQuery Sq = new SelectQuery("Lenovo_BiosSetting");
     ManagementObjectSearcher objOSDetails = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Sq);
     ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = objOSDetails.Get();
     foreach (ManagementObject MO in osDetailsCollection)
     {
         if (MO["CurrentSetting"].ToString().Contains("WakeOnLAN"))
     {
         string[] arr = new string[3];
         ListViewItem itm;
         //add items to ListView
         arr[0] = "";
         arr[1] = "WakeOnLAN";
         arr[2] = MO["CurrentSetting"].ToString();
         itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
         listView200.Items.Add(itm);
    }
}
```

Adrian

Comment: I would change the .Contains to look use the .ToUpper() function in case the name is of different type..

Comment: Hi MethodMan, THX for the tip. I will change the code when I have some time.